# How to re-arrange this df in groups of 3

Tags: python, pandas

I have a shortened version of my real data in which I would like to re-arrange as described below.

**Input:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  
data4 = [[45], [285], [256], [55], [360], [213], [65], [435], [368]]
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data4)
```

**Output:**

```
     0
0   45
1  285
2  256
3   55
4  360
5  213
6   65
7  435
8  368
```

**Desired Output:**

```
    0    1    2
0  45  285  256
1  55  360  213
2  65  435  368
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With np.reshape: `pd.DataFrame(df4.values.reshape(-1, 3))`

Answer (score 1):

With `pivot()` :

```
df4["count"] = df4.index%3
df4.pivot(index=None, columns="count", values=0).bfill().iloc[::3, :].reset_index(drop=True)
```